# Stored property requires an initial value or should be @NSManaged

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, properties, nsmanagedobject

I'm attempting to convert [Apple's sample code](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/DateSectionTitles/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009939) for creating a custom section identifier for Core Data in order to properly sort/label the sections in a table view from Objective-C into Swift. They have implemented a setter for a non-transient property declared as `@dynamic` so they can invalidate the identifier when the time changes. I thought I would just use `didSet` on the `@NSManaged` property, but Xcode throws an error: `Stored property requires an initial value or should be @NSManaged`.

How can this be appropriately converted to obtain the desired behavior?

```
@property (nonatomic) NSDate *primitiveTimeStamp;
@property (nonatomic) NSString *primitiveSectionIdentifier;

@dynamic title, timeStamp, primitiveTimeStamp, sectionIdentifier, primitiveSectionIdentifier;

- (void)setTimeStamp:(NSDate *)newDate {
    // If the time stamp changes, the section identifier become invalid.
    [self willChangeValueForKey:@"timeStamp"];
    [self setPrimitiveTimeStamp:newDate];
    [self didChangeValueForKey:@"timeStamp"];

    [self setPrimitiveSectionIdentifier:nil];
}
```

I've tried:

```
var primitiveTimeStamp: NSDate?
var primitiveSectionIdentifier: String?

@NSManaged var timeStamp: NSDate { //error here
    didSet {
        self.willChangeValueForKey("timeStamp")
        self.primitiveDate = timeStamp
        self.didChangeValueForKey("timeStamp")

        self.primitiveSectionIdentifier = nil
    }
}
```

I also tried taking off `@NSManaged` and just use `var timeStamp: NSDate!`, then place the code in `didSet`, and this actually worked great for the first launch - I could create an object and store it and view it in the proper section in the table. But on subsequent launches, the `timeStamp` property is `nil` so the app crashes when trying to generate a `sectionIdentifier`.

Comment: Is `timeStamp` a transient property? If not, why don't you use `NSFetchedResultsController`? It allows you to sort your data into sections...

Comment: @POB no timeStamp is not transient and I am using a fetched results controller but I need a transient property titled sectionIdentifier to obtain the desired identifier in order to sort it properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`timeStamp` you defined is a stored property rather than a computed property. Computed property may not have didSet/didGet observers.

> You don't need to define property observers for non-overridden computed properties, because you can observe and respond to changes to their value from directly within the computed property's setter.

```
var primitiveTimeStamp: NSDate?
var primitiveSectionIdentifier: String?

var timeStamp: NSDate {
  get {
    return self.primitiveDate
  }

  set {
    self.willChangeValueForKey("timeStamp")
    self.primitiveDate = newValue
    self.didChangeValueForKey("timeStamp")

    self.primitiveSectionIdentifier = nil
  }
}
```

Since a computed property should have only a getter, or both setter/getter, you have to also set the getter.

I am not testing the code, but they may solve you problem.

PS: If you want to set property observers for your computed properties, you can subclass you classes and add property observers to the inherited properties.

Comment: What would you return in the getter though?

Comment: @RobNapier Thanks, with that setup it seems to be working without issue.